# Vue: How to access props data in created function?

Tags: vue.js

I'm passing an array of objects into a child component and I want to access this array into the created function of the child component.

When logging the entire `this.$props` object I'm getting all the data however when I'm logging the array I'm getting an empty proxy object.

**Parent component**

```
<script>
    import SelectWithSearch from '@/components/formElements/SelectWithSearch.vue';
    import AddressService from '@/services/AddressService';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                city: 312,
                cityOptions: [],
            };
        },
        components: { SelectWithSearch },
        created() {
            this.getCities();
        },
        methods: {
            async getCities() {
                const response = await AddressService.getCities();
                this.cityOptions = response.data.cities.map((city) => {
                    return {
                        id: city.id,
                        display_name: `${city.sub_city} (${city.zip})`,
                    };
                });
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

**Child component (SelectWithSearch)**

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            label: { type: String, required: false },
            options: { type: Array, required: true },
        },
        created() {
            console.log(this.$props);
            console.log(this.$props.options);
            console.log(this.options);
            console.log(this.label);
        },
```

**Output**

[image]
[image]

How can I access the options data in the created function?

Comment: As the data is loaded asynchronously you can't as the data is not there yet. The reason you see the data in the console is only because most modern browser show "live" data in the console if you log an object (you see last value and not value at the time log command was executed)

Comment: @MichalLevý Interesting! Didn't know modern browsers worked that way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects